# How to move Azure SQL managed instance cross tenants?

Tags: migration, azure-sql-managed-instance

How to move Azure SQL managed instance cross tenants?

I have some critical DBs hosted by Tenant_A's SQL MI A which need to be moved to Tenant_B's SQL MI B. They are all TDE encrypted by CMK.

Is there any way to migrate them with minimal downtime?

I know the traditional way:

Stop the application to avoid data flying -> decrypt DB -> Make a copy-only backup to the storage account -> Copy over the backup file to the target storage account -> restore the backup from the target storage account to the target SQL MI -> encrypt DB on the target SQL MI -> Start the application to point to the target SQL MI.

Since the DB size is huge, it will be a long downtime.

Another way is using replication, but if we use replication, at the first beginning, we need to generate a snapshot, which will put the locks on the production database, and impact the user. As I mentioned, it's a critical application and looks like that is also out of option...

How can I avoid it?

Many thanks,

Comment: How many Tables and Views exist in the source database, roughly?

Comment: Hi J.D. There are 100 + tables and only 1 view there

Comment: Any updates on this topic? Thanks,